# Console log click control

Tags: javascript

```
var selected = [
  "Apples",
  "Bananas",
];



var selectedrandom = selected[Math.floor(Math.random()*selected.length)];

setTimeout(

    function() {
document.getElementById("coordinateTargetFirstTime").value = randomselected ; }, (Math.random() * 500) + 3000);
```

This one I created works properly but need it
to click on two buttons when choosing an apple and how to achieve this when choosing a banana on another two buttons?

```
setTimeout(function() {     document.querySelectorAll("input[value='Apples1']")[0].click();    }, (Math.random() * 1000) + 4000);

setTimeout(function() {     document.querySelectorAll("input[value='Apples1']")[0].click();    }, (Math.random() * 1000) + 5000);
```

they need not to blink for the other two elements Apples click and Bananas no

principe if ? and     console.log(selectedrandom);

```
setTimeout(function() {     document.querySelectorAll("input[value='Bananas1']")[0].click();    }, (Math.random() * 1000) + 3000);

setTimeout(function() {     document.querySelectorAll("input[value='Bananas1']")[0].click();    }, (Math.random() * 1000) + 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome @John Deatd to this community.

I am not sure whether I understood correctly your question, hence I offer following approach, which you then can comment on in order to get it right.

In a list of options you can achieve the `click()`-Event programmatically by triggering the

`change()`-Event with `.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))`, which simulates a user's click on the options list.

Then, you define your `.onchange = function() { ... }`

```js
const selected = [
  'Apples',
  'Bananas'
];

const fruitOptions = document.getElementById('coordinateTargetFirstTime');
  //let's declare that element as a variable

let selectedrandom = selected[Math.floor(Math.random()*selected.length)];

setTimeout(function() {
  fruitOptions.value = selectedrandom;
}, (Math.random() * 500) + 3000);

setTimeout(function() {
  fruitOptions.value = 'Apples';
  fruitOptions.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    //this simulates the click-event, because if user clicks it generates a change-event
}, (Math.random() * 1000) + 4000);

setTimeout(function() {
  fruitOptions.value = 'Bananas';
  fruitOptions.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    //this simulates the click-event, because if user clicks it generates a change-event
}, (Math.random() * 1000) + 5000);

   //and here comes the function that runs on each change
fruitOptions.onchange = function() {
  if(this.value == 'Apples') {
    document.getElementById('Apples1').click();
    document.getElementById('Apples1').classList.add('clicked');
    console.log('button Apples1 clicked');
  };
  if(this.value == 'Bananas') {
    document.getElementById('Bananas1').click();
    document.getElementById('Bananas1').classList.add('clicked');
    console.log('button Bananas1 clicked');
  }
};
```

```css
  button.clicked {
    background-color: lime;
  }
```

```html
<label for='coordinateTargetFirstTime'>Choose a fruit:</label><br><br>
<select id='coordinateTargetFirstTime' name='coordinateTargetFirstTime' size='2'>
  <option value='Apples'>Apples</option>
  <option value='Bananas'>Bananas</option>
</select>

<button id='Apples1'>Apples1</button>
<button id='Bananas1'>Bananas1</button>
```

As you are a new member, please note that you can Click above the blue button "**Run Code Snippet**" and see the code running.

Keep coding and let us know whether this is what you were looking for.

Comment: @ Juergen Fink yes something like that i thought thank you works it well